# Objective c - innerMenu on viewController, and scroll to content

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, scroll, sidebar

this is a two parts question, the first one is about, how to make an inner menu like the "pop up" menu on what's app, when u want to send an imagen or something to a contact. (IOS 7)

and then, link each element on that "pop up menu" to a title on the content of my view controller text, i mean scroll to that title.

the content should be something like this:

> A title:
>
> description for title ...
>
> seecond title:
>
> a description for that another title...
>
> third title:
>
> a description for that last title...

the menu should be something like:

> - a title
> - second title
> - third title

and when i click some of those items, the app scroll to each one...

any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the example you are referring to? Many people reading this will not have Whatsapp and won't know anything about it.

Comment: http://appsaga.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/whatsapp-location-sharing-choices.jpg

this link, contains the menu, but isn't ios 7...
but, well, that's the main idea...  Thank you !

Comment: That's just a `UIActionSheet`. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yeah, the first one, but, the second one is the most heavy, don't u think ?, any ideas to make that "setscroll" to the textview ? and how to know what is the "y" coordinate of each title ?

Comment: I only see one screenshot so I'm not sure what you're talking about. Did you forget to post the second one?

Comment: there's no screen shots for that one, it's something that i just have the idea, but i think that on the main question is a good explanation of what i want to create... items of that UIActionSheet make the uiTextView scroll to each part of the content... if this is not in off, ill make the image and  link it... thanks !

Comment: That would probably help as your description is not super clear to me.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24979665/explain-stack.jpg i think that should explain a little bit more the main idea of the interaction that i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said before the overlay is just a `UIActionSheet`.

Assuming you are using a `UITableView`, as long as you have a mapping of section title to section index, you can just tell the table to scroll to that index using the `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`
 method.

Say the user selected the title corresponding to the third section (at index 2), you can just do something like:

```
[myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:2] atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks ! the actionsheet is working fine now, but, as i've said on the question, it isn't a tableView but a textView. i've found this method of textView Class [**scrollRangeToVisible:**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uitextview_class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextView/scrollRangeToVisible:) and i hope it work as the name says : )

Comment: if i'm not using an UITableView, but a WebView !? there's a way to make the scroll ??

Comment: @user3430487, a `UIWebView` exposes its internal `UIScrollView` as a property called `scrollView`. So you can just do `[myWebView.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:animated];`

Comment: It's just a constant provided by CGGeometry for convenience. It is the same as writing `CGPointMake(0,0)`.